# Getting SQL values with PHP into jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, sql, jspdf

I've currrently working on an invoice system and am trying to export the invoices as a PDF. The PDF creation should be done with jsPDF and the Values for the Invoice (Customer,Adress,Ordernumber etc.) are in an SQL DB.
My Plan was, that the .js program which creates the PDF file gets the document from an other PHP document.

```
var AnRD =      <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveAnRD(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var AbRD =      <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveAbRD(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var VName =     <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveVorname(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var NName =     <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveNachname(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var Strasse =   <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveStarsse(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var Hnummer =   <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveHnummer(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var PLZ =       <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(givePLZ(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var Ort =       <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveOrt(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
var Anrede =    <?php include "GetData.php"; return json_encode(giveAn(ResID), JSON_HEX_TAG);?>;;
```

The document GetData.php looks like that:

```
include "../dblogin.php";
$resID="";


$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
//##############################################
function giveAnRD($resID)
{
    $AnRD = "SELECT reserviert_von FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    return $AnRD;
}
//##############################################
function giveHausName($resID)
{
    $HID = "SELECT HausID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $AnRD = "SELECT Hausname FROM hauser WHERE HausID = $HID";
    return $AnRD;
}
//##############################################
function giveAbRD($resID)
{
    $AnRD = "SELECT reserviert_bis FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    return $AnRD;
}
//##############################################
function giveAnrede($resID)
{
$PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
$TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";

    if ($TITEL =! NULL)
    {
        $Anrede = $GEN . ' ' . $TITEL;
    }

    else
    {
        $Anrede = $GEN;
    }
$GEN = "SELECT Anrede FROM persons WHERE PersonID = $PID";
return $GEN;
}
//##############################################
function giveVorname($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
//##############################################
function giveNachname($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
//##############################################
function giveStrasse($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
//##############################################
function giveHnummer($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
//##############################################
function givePLZ($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
//##############################################
function giveOrt($resID)
{
    $PID = "SELECT PersonID FROM reservierungen WHERE ReservierungsID = $resID";
    $TITEL = "SELECT Titel FROM persons WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = $PID";
    return $TITEL;
}
```

Any Idea, why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance

docunhown

Comment: 1) How is it not working?; 2) Show us the steps in which you tried to track down the problem.

Comment: 3) In PHP, if you double quote a string and insert valid variables (e.g `$PID`) in it, it creates a [variable string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) and the variable will be replaced by the value of the variable referenced, so if we have `$foo = 'bar'; $foobar = "foo$bar";`, then `$foobar` becomes `foobar`; 4) SQL Error: `WHERE PersonID AND IS NOT NULL = 'SomeValue'` makes no sense. Did you mean `WHERE PersonID = 'SomeValue'`?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 To The SQL Error you mentioned: the `AND IS NOT NULL` was put there, because the Field `Anrede` might be Null, but I removed it from the code. Thanks for the advice. To 1): Normally, when I execute the code js code, a PDF File should be executed. but after I replaced the Fields with for example the var for the name, I don't get any response from the file.

Comment: The PDF Creation now looks like this:
`doc.setFontType("bold");
 doc.text(20, 82, PLZ + ' ' + Ort);`